# Collapse certain rows using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, row

I'm new to r, and attempting to collapse specific rows of numeric data using dplyr. All the data is int, I have an ID variable and 8 other variables in a 9 by 8 table. If I want to collapse all the data in rows 2 and 3 and 4 and 5, how would I do that?

I've tried to use group_by and summarise but it doesn't seem like I'm inputting the right code.

Comment: You should provide some data for us to better understand your problem. Provide the ouptut of `dput(df)` into your question, and show the desired output. Also, what does "collapse" mean here - for example are you trying to sum rows 2 thru 5 into a single row?

Comment: Ok, here is the output from dput(df) 

structure(list(ID = 1:8, V1 = c(50L, 16L, 12L, 11L, 2L, 12L, 
0L, 0L), V2 = c(19L, 40L, 35L, 20L, 8L, 28L, 6L, 3L), V3 = c(26L, 
34L, 65L, 58L, 12L, 102L, 19L, 14L), V4 = c(8L, 18L, 66L, 110L, 
23L, 162L, 40L, 32L), V5 = c(7L, 11L, 35L, 40L, 25L, 90L, 21L, 
15L), V6 = c(11L, 20L, 88L, 183L, 46L, 554L, 158L, 126L), V7 = c(6L, 
8L, 23L, 64L, 28L, 230L, 143L, 91L), V8 = c(2L, 3L, 21L, 32L, 
12L, 177L, 71L, 106L)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I want to sum rows 2 and 3, and 4 and 5 for example. Creating a new row 2 (which would be the old 2 and 3) and creating a new row 3 (which would be the old 4 and 5 rows). The ID values are from 1:8. Not sure of the best way to show the desired output.

Comment: rprince, please [edit] your question and place the sample data _there_ inside of a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Code and sample-data don't always format as well in comments, and comments can be skipped by the reader or hidden by Stack's interface. Thanks.

Comment: Further, "collapse" could be several things: summarize (sum); `paste` into single strings; or convert into a list-column or embedded frame. What is your expected output?

Comment: By collapse I meant to sum, for instance to sum rows 2 and 3, to create a new second row comprised of all the summed values across all variables.